# how to search multiple of word in a data frame rows?

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe, nlp

Let's see my dataframe,

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
'Tweets' : ['This is bad', 'This is terrible', 'This is good', 'This is great but trouble of life']})

negative_words = ['bad', 'terrible', 'trouble of life']
```

Here I need to extract the negative_words from dataframe.

my code is only extract the single word in negative_words.

```
data['searched_text'] =  data['Tweets'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(entry for tag in x.split() for entry in negative_words if tag == entry))
```

expected output should include the 'trouble of life' word also in the column.

Comment: in your condition you check each item in your list of negative words against a splitted string of each row, which means you compare `"trouble of life" == "trouble"`, then `"trouble of life" == "of"` ...this never is True

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Update**
We can use regex to prevent a match if the bad word is part of a bigger word.

changed the input a bit for demonstration:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
'Tweets' : ['This is bad', 
            'This is terrible', 
            'This is good', 
            'This is great but trouble of life', 
            'This is a badge', 
            'This is trouble life', 
            'This is b ad']
})

negative_words = ['bad', 'terrible', 'trouble of life']
```

```py
import re

data['searched_text'] =  data['Tweets'].apply(lambda row: ''.join(tag for tag in negative_words if re.search(fr"\b{tag}\b", row)))
print(data)
```

Output:

```
                              Tweets    searched_text
0                        This is bad              bad
1                   This is terrible         terrible
2                       This is good                 
3  This is great but trouble of life  trouble of life
4                    This is a badge                 
5               This is trouble life                 
6                       This is b ad
```

```py
data['searched_text'] =  data['Tweets'].apply(lambda row: ''.join(tag for tag in negative_words if tag in row))
```

Output:

```
                              Tweets    searched_text
0                        This is bad              bad
1                   This is terrible         terrible
2                       This is good                 
3  This is great but trouble of life  trouble of life
```

Comment: thanks but if there have a word that contain the negative_words as part of it, for ex: badge that contain bad there search_text should not return the bad there, but it return here as bad.

Comment: I updateed my answer, now it should work

Comment: You never accepted an answer in all of your question on SO. Please consider doing that if you get a correct answer to your question beside upvoting (the check under the voting button)